# PowerShell Process Name using c#

Tags: c#, powershell, whitespace, psobject

I'm question.

I get process name througth powershell script using c#.
But, i did not get value because process name contains whitespace.

How can I get value to contains whitespace in powershell using c#?

Comment: Your `scriptText` is not valid PowerShell. What does `s = Get-Process | ?{$_.Id -eq '21952'}` mean? Variables have `$` in front of them. Where are the semicolons (`;`) between statements?

Comment: On my machine, `Get-Process` takes an `-Id` parameter, so you could simplify the assignment to `$s = Get-Process -Id 21952`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PowerShell to get processes.

This sample line gives you the ID/Name for all processes with ID 21952 (although I suspect you won't have one with ID 21952).

```
 var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.Id == 21952).ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p => p.ProcessName);
```

To remove that filter:

```
 var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p => p.ProcessName);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I must use powershell. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following directly in C#

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
int pid = 21952;
Process localById = Process.GetProcessById(pid);

Console.WriteLine($"Process name for pid {pid}: '{localById.ProcessName}' '{localById.MainModule.FileName}'");
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I must use powershell. Is there a way?